# В чём смысл значка пустой строки на примере

Tags: javascript

Читаю самоучитель по JavaScript https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse. Возник вопрос при рассмотрении первого же примера:

Какую роль здесь играют две кавычки '' перед скобкой в конце первой строки?

```
let year = prompt('В каком году была опубликована спецификация ECMAScript-2015?', '');

if (year == 2015) alert( 'Вы правы!' );
```

Answer (score 3):

Функция `prompt` принимает два аргумента:

```
prompt(title, [default]);
```

`title` - Текст для отображения в окне.

`default` - Необязательный второй параметр, который устанавливает начальное значение в поле для текста в окне.

В принципе, можно опустить. Но с IE может не сработать и такой хак может быть применён именно для него

Answer (score 1):

Это начальное значение, и в современных браузерах оно может не указываться.

Был когда-то какой-то IE (мне кажется, что не все версии, а только старые), который если не передать пустую строку, выводил `undefined`.

PS: А ведь там об этом тоже [рассказывается](https://learn.javascript.ru/alert-prompt-confirm#fhsequfmlc).